# Labels in the center of Tikz-cd diagrams

Tags: tikz-cd

How do I get the $\Sigma_i$ to appear in the center of a diagram as in the following [image]

Thanks!

Comment: The sigmas are halfway between the corners, for which you presumably have coordinates.  you can compute the midpoints, use `\path (A) -- node[midway]{\$Sigma_1$} (C);` or  use the calc tikzlibrary and use `\node at ($(A)!.5!(C)$) ($\Sigma_1};`

Answer (score 6):

One way is to increase the size of the grid to 3x5. The `\Sigma`s would then be in the second row, columns 2 and 4.

[image]

If you would prefer the `\Sigma`s to be the same size as `\psi`, `\varphi` and `\theta`, you can use `\scriptstyle{\Sigma_1}`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=.5cm]
  A'\arrow[rr,"\alpha_1"]\arrow[dd,"\psi"] && A\arrow[rr,"\alpha_2"]\arrow[dd,"\varphi"] && A''\arrow[dd,"\theta"]\\
  & \Sigma_1 && \Sigma_2\\
  B'\arrow[rr,"\beta_1"] && B\arrow[rr,"\beta_2"] && B''
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can name arrows and make (phantom) arrows between them.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
A' \arrow[r,"\alpha_1"] \arrow[d,"\psi",""{name=D1}] &
  A \arrow[r,"\alpha_2"] \arrow[d,"\varphi",""{name=D2}] &
  A'' \arrow[d,"\theta",""{name=D3}]\\
B' \arrow[r,"\beta_1"] &
  B\arrow[r,"\beta_2"] &
  B''
\arrow[phantom,from=D1,to=D2,"\scriptstyle\Sigma_1"]
\arrow[phantom,from=D2,to=D3,"\scriptstyle\Sigma_2"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]